# How to set print preview options at javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, printing

I need to change options [print-preview-any-browser.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf94X.png) at print preview page. How can i change these settings?

Btw, i can change page style with css but i don't need css code. It didn't change any print preview option.

Best Regards.

Comment: You can't. It is outside the realm of JavaScript.

Comment: These are **functionalities specific to each browser**. Its not something you can control by your code.

Comment: Thanks your answers